# the ruby source code generated by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I  an new in ruby and rails.

Following the guide in ror document,I create the blog application.

Howver when I see the code generated,I found that I can not understand them,for exmpale:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

The repond_to is a method(isn't it?),and the following block is the argument?

However what does the code inner the block mean?

```
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
```

Is the format.html is the name of the method or something else?

ANd how about the `{ render json: @post }`>?

Comment: Have you tried reading some [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to)?

Comment: I do not mean the function of the method,but the expression here.

Comment: You need some basic ruby education, it will clear this up faster than anything else. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/

Comment: Check Ruby for Rails book by David Black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `respond_to` method helps you to deliver the content in the format requested. For example, if you call `/posts/1.json`, the response would be a JSON file. If it's `/posts/1.html`, the response would be an HTML page. The default when no extension is provided is to render HTML.

The `format.json` method tells Rails what to do when requested that extension, like for example, if for every JSON request you would like to increase a counter, but not for HTML requests, you could do:

```
format.json { 
    counter = counter + 1
    render json: @post
}
```

If you don't provide a block to the `format.json` method, Rails automagically will try and look inside `views/posts/` for a `show.json.erb` file, and render that. In the method you provided, `render json: @post` tells Rails to render it immediately instead of looking for a file.

Comment: I know this render different result according to the request type(json or html),I just can not understand this syntax.  so `format` here is an object? and `format.json` is a method,and the `{xx}` is the argument of block type? and inside the block,the `render` is another method name,and the `json:@post` is the argument?

Comment: @hguser, your assumptions about what's method and what's arguments in that case are right if that's what you're asking about. `render json: @post` is equivalent of `render({ :json => @post })` if that'd make things clearer for you.